# Plotly choropleth maps only plot last element of data frame

Tags: python, plotly

I use Plotly express choropleth to plot some data into a map but it draws a boundary line only for the last element of the input data frame. and it draws a boundary line for each area if gave an individual row correctly. this is an input data frame,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/22fz7.png
this is output is gave,
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAH8u.png
here is the code block i used,
`fig = px.choropleth(grand_summery,geojson=geo_data,color='total_cases', locations='district',featureidkey='properties.ADM2_EN') fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', visible=False) fig.show()`

geojson file I got from this repo - https://github.com/MalakaGu/Sri-lanka-maps/blob/master/discrict_map/District_geo.json

dataframe as a csv file- https://github.com/ashen007/SL_COVID_analysis/blob/master/data/exp_df.csv

Comment: which geojson file/url do you use? What is the source of `geo_data`?

Comment: and could you please post the the dataframe as text, not as picture?

Comment: I thought that the polygon information in the geojson file might not be correct, so I tried it with folium. It seems that the geojson file is not the cause.

Comment: in geojson data did you remove the first feature? is it okay to keep it because it's province data and it didn't have `ADM2_EN` value which I used to map geodata with data frame. and also when import this JSON `json.load` give an error so I used `utf-8` encoding to load, is it can be the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the results in the Collab environment? As you commented, the first data in GEOJSON is 'unknown', which was bothering me, but it's a contour, so I don't think it's a problem. I did not delete it. As you commented, the first data in GEOJSON is 'unknown', but I didn't delete it, and if it reads fine in UTF-8, I think it's fine.

Comment: There could be an issue with the geo json. When I run `with urlopen('https://github.com/MalakaGu/Sri-lanka-maps/blob/master/discrict_map/District_geo.json') as response: geo_data = json.load(response)` I see the error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)`

Comment: Hi, I inspected your code and it looks fine, I got the same result. Actually the geojson data are inversed somehow (except for the [unknown] region...), such that it draws each district as a shape filling the entire map _around_ the actual district shape (like a negative, the contour coordinates are correct). That's why each feature seems to override the previous one, Plotly associates the _total_cases_ color for each district and fills the outside of their shape while the inside is left with the previous fill colour.