# Plotly choropleth map draws 1 feature and fills background with one color

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

For a project I need to draw a choropleth map of Belgium and it's provinces.
When I draw the map I get this as a result.
[image]

I use the following python code to draw the map:

```
import plotly.express as px
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data/resulted_data/kmeans/CLUSTER_PROVINCES.csv")
with open('geojson.json') as file:
    be = json.load(file)

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=be, locations="PROVINCE", featureidkey="properties.NameDUT", projection="mercator", color="CLUSTER", hover_data=["PROVINCE", "INFECTION_RATE", "HOSPITALISATION_RATE", "TEST_POS_PERCENTAGE", "CLUSTER"])

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")

fig.show()
```

The geojson file I use works on geojson.io. The result on geojson.io is the following:
[image]

The used geojson file can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathiasleroy/Belgium-Geographic-Data/master/dist/polygons/geojson/Belgium.provinces.WGS84.geojson.
The only thing I changed in the geojson file is the value of the Dutch names for the provinces to match the names in my dataset.

I have no idea why it plots the province of Antwerp right but then covers the background with the same color.

Comment: This seems related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67753862/2529954, I made an explanation attempt in a comment but no solution came out.

Comment: Would you have any knowledge on how to change the geojson file so it's not inversed anymore? I'm new to working with geojson so I have no idea how it actually works internally.

Comment: When drawing the provinces each by itself, I can see that you are right. The outside of the provinces get colored. Do you have any way to fix this?

Comment: When trying one province on geojson.io it works perfectly though

Comment: I have no idea how to deal with that type of geojson, but I'm pretty sure there is a way to plot it correctly because all coordinates tell the same thing, it's all about how polygons are filled. It is worth creating an issue on plotly's github, even if it's not plotly's fault, developers may already have encounter this problem and could provide a solution or a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the geojson file is badly wound.

A solution to the problem can be found here: [Solution](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3248)