# How to use plotly with geodataframe geometry

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas, choropleth

I want to plot a geojson/geometry map with plotly sliders (for time).
Here's what my gdf looks like:

```
gdf.head()
                                            
|     |  key  |  value  | geometry                                            |
| --- | ----- | ------- | --------------------------------------------------- |
|  0  | key1  | 33.094  | MULTIPOLYGON (((-93.50080 38.17240, -93.49680 ...   |
|  1  | key2  | 33.833  | MULTIPOLYGON (((-114.06920 48.99950, -114.0644...   |
|  2  | key3  | 30.000  | MULTIPOLYGON (((-118.83760 49.00000, -118.8360...   |
|  3  | key4  | 29.010  | MULTIPOLYGON (((-110.58290 32.04520, -110.4543...   |

(where key are strings)
```

and I have several files for different years and months that has different values correspond to key/geometry pair. I want to plot something so I have a time slider and can easily visualize the value change of each region along the time. I see plotly could potentially do this ([link](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/)) , and this is what I want, but I'm not able to get there:

[image: example plot]

In plotly, one way to take advantage of slider is to use `fig.add_trace()` and add plotly plots to it. So I'm trying to use the example code on plotly for `px.choropleth()` but still not able to show my polygons.

I also did `gdf.explode(ignore_index=True)` to explode 'geometry' from MULTIPLOLYGON to POLYGON, but still nothing changed.

overall the code looks like this:

```
gdf = geopandas.read_file(file_path)
gdf = gdf.explode(ignore_index=True)

fig = px.choropleth(
    gdf,
    geojson=gdf.geometry,
    color='value',
    scope="north america",
    locations=gdf.key
)
fig.show()
```

and the plot like this:
[image: plot with px.choropleth]

While if I directly use `gdf.plot()` either explode or not, I got this:
[image: plot with geopandas]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use links to support your question, but please include all the info in a question so it can stand on its own without external sources. So rather than calling a link <link>, describe what you’re actually linking to and include the relevant description, image, or code snippet to give us a sense of what you’re hoping we’d get from the external source. This ensures your question will last if the links break and also makes it more likely others will help you out (following all these links is cumbersome for us). Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for the comment, I just modified the question and hope it will be more readable

Comment: I just wanna say, this is a pretty clear first question, welcome to the site Dayuan I hope you will get a great answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question did not have sample data, I used the data in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#indexing-by-geojson-properties) and expanded it to the five-year district-by-district polling results. Now the data is ready for the animated slider. I also set up a CRS for the json in the reference as geometry and loaded it as a geopandas data frame. The geojson specification in my map creation code is using an interface that converts from the geopandas data frame I just created to geojson. Please replace the key column in the question with the district column in my answer.

```
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = px.data.election()

dff = pd.DataFrame({'district': df['district'].tolist()*5,#np.repeat(df['district'],5),
                    'total': np.random.randint(5000,12000,len(df)*5),
                    'year': sum([[x]*len(df) for x in np.arange(2017, 2022,1)],[])
                   })

geojson = px.data.election_geojson()
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson,  crs='epsg:4326')

fig = px.choropleth(dff,
                    geojson=gdf.__geo_interface__,
                    color="total",
                    animation_frame='year',
                    locations="district",
                    featureidkey="properties.district",
                    projection="mercator",
                    color_continuous_scale="deep"
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(height=500,width=500)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for. And it turns out that:
1. you can use this to plot MULTIPOLYGON and POLYGON both.
2. locations has to be defined within choropleth plot, I ended up using df.index
3. I also faced the issue in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000241/plotly-choropleth-map-draws-1-feature-and-fills-background-with-one-color) where I need to rewind order of POLYGON coords, I think the order of coords (clockwise or counter-clockwise) matters when coloring choropleth plot, whereas plot() covers up this issue.